# Moving items cells in groups of 10 to another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of items in Excel all in 1 column (D6:D1000+)

I am trying to create a macro to move items over to the next column to the right in groups of 15's.

So D6:D21 stays there, then D22:D37 should move to E6:E21, D38:D53 move to F6:F21 and so on...

I found some code from googling and I was giving the below code ago but i was getting an out of bounds error.

```
Sub SplitInto15CellsPerColumn()
  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, vArrIn As Variant, vArrOut As Variant
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
  vArrIn = Range("D6:D" & LastRow)
  ReDim vArrOut(1 To 15, 1 To Int(LastRow / 15) + 1)
  For X = 0 To LastRow - 1
    vArrOut(1 + (X Mod 15), 1 + Int(X / 15)) = vArrIn(X + 1, 1)
  Next
  Range("B1").Resize(15, UBound(vArrOut, 2)) = vArrOut
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For X = 0 To LastRow - 1
```

you should use

```
For X = 0 To LastRow - 6
```

Since your source table starts in 6.

Also, check  (by doing MsgBox LastRow)  that you indeed get the correct value for LastRow

Comment: and i needed to change

      Next
  Range("E6").Resize(15, UBound(vArrOut, 2)) = vArrOut -- note E6, it now works. thanks!